# Sound Settings is missing all output devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, system-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My sound stopped working today, how can I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25622/my-sound-stopped-working-today-how-can-i-fix-it)

I'm baffled by this discrepancy:

1. This speaker test is successful:

   ```
   speaker-test -c 6 -D 'surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0'
   ```
2. Sound Settings is behaving as if I have no sound card:

   [image: Sound Settings]

How do I find out what's causing this problem?

### Details

Have a look at [`aplay -L`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149561/), [`pacmd list-cards`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149840/), [`lshw`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149588/), [`pulseaudio -vvvv`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149905/), and [pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqrVs.png). I do not use HDMI.

[This discussion](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2011-June/010321.html) of a similar problem on a PulseAudio mailing list suggests that changes to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` might be responsible, but I have not edited this file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was running into [Bug #590780: Installing "randomsound" package causes Pulseaudio to stop functioning at reboot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/randomsound/+bug/590780) and didn't know it yet. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/25632/1859):

> 1. Run `pstree | less`
> 2. In that, type `/arecord` and press return to find the `arecord` process.
> 3. Press up once and you'll see its parent. In my case this was `randomsound`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rebuild the alsa sound module? If no, try the following:

```
sudo apt install module-assistant build-essential

sudo module-assistant prepare,update

sudo module-assistant build,install alsa

sudo depmod
```

This should reset your sound settings.

Comment: Which "sound settings" does this reset, and why do you recommend doing this? I'm not yet convinced that the problem is within ALSA, since it appears to [detect my sound cards correctly](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149561/).

Comment: "Sound settings" corresponding to the image you linked above in your question. ALSA y detecting your sound card but isn't showing it in the "selec device" section. after this it should show it.