# No sound output, all sound setting greyed out

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3, there was no sound output. A couple of devices were identified, and a dummy showed up, selecting none of those worked. Speaker test nil.

At first I thought it was a codec problem, so I installed VLC but still no luck.

I tried some stuff with alsa (read in a forum), which seems to have made it worse as now no devices are showing at all. All sound settings greyed out, and sometimes pop up again - unstable. Test gives no result either in settings or terminal.

[output devices shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te6xI.png)

[speaker-test output in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILUGE.png)

Log shows:

> [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="platform-bytcr_rt5651" card_name="alsa_card.platform-bytcr_rt5651" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
>
> [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
>
> Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port

Can someone please help?

Would rebuilding ALSA be a good first step? As is here:
[Sound Settings is missing all output devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176295/sound-settings-is-missing-all-output-devices) > *This did not work for me.*

I'm a complete newbie so don't want to give any more false steps here.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried to install the driver needed? You can go to Software & Updates, then go to Additional Drivers, and look if there's a driver for that.

May i know how you set up your system? Is it onboard audio / DAC Dongle or anything else?

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks for the reply. No additional drivers in updates. No idea of the setup. How do I find out? If this furthers, it's a cheap laptop.

Comment: @Chris Could this be it? 00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
 [virtual] Memory at 91000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
 Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
 Kernel driver in use: intel_atomisp2_pm
 Kernel modules: intel_atomisp2_pm

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

https://github.com/plbossart/UCM/issues/13#issuecomment-399256736

Basically installing the driver, selecting the right output in alsamixer and waiting a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Tried Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB and this issue is fixed. This processor sound capability is now supported out of the box.